# Android Fragment Testing Error: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes

Tags: android, android-testing

Working on Android Fragment Testing but the test process is crashing as illustrated below:
[image]

Logcat shows this error:
[image]

Gradle(app) - I am using these Fragment Test Libraries:
[image]

Googled this error which is something to do with jar file signing and the recommended solution is to include this code on the gradle app.

[image]

Unfortunately this is not working. Will appreciate your help on this.

Comment: My instrumentation unit tests crashed with error

`2 files found with path 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'.`
and
`2 files found with path 'META-INF/AL2.0'.`
for which I added 
`packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/AL2.0'
}`

This removed all errors and tests ran fine.

As per the old gradle plugin documentation the default values of pickFirst is none and exclude is all signature files.

In your above signature exclusions, `*.EC signatures` are not excluded, maybe this can help

Comment: Old android gradle documentation https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/3.2/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html